# how connect a mysql connection after destroy it in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

my code is this(It's about like this):

```
this.con = mysql.createConnection({...});
this.con.connect(); // No error
this.con.destroy();
.......
.......
this.con.connect(); // error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after being destroyed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-create/re-assign the connection before connecting again:
`this.con = mysql.createConnection({...});`

Comment: I think createConnection instantiate new object of mysq connection than not good!

Comment: Ok well maybe a connection pool is more what you want? Check out the docs here under “Pooling connections”: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql